# Iframe HTML without src

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I Have this code inside a website

```
<iframe src="" name="" width="" height="">

        <html>
        <head>
            <meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
            <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
            <meta property="og:description" content="This Is The Description Section" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>    (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="@Request.Url" data-width="300" data-num-posts="3"></div>

        </body>
        </html>
        </iframe>
```

this code is not working, but i don't know why? can any one help me?

Comment: what is your intention? thats is not how is supposed to be used an iframe

Comment: Define "not working"? What do you expect to happen? An iframe can't contain content directly, set the `src` attribute to an URL from where you serve the content.

Comment: i want to user the facebook comments inside this iframe

Comment: i want to write the html inside the iframe because i want to change it's content

Comment: why don't you point your `src` to a asp page that do what you want?!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895872/add-metatags-using-javascript

Comment: @IbrahemAhmedShehata if you want to change that thing with javascript, then you could simply use a `div` instead of an `iframe`

Comment: the problem is that facebook take image, description etc... from the meta tags and i can't change them using javascript(facebook don't recognize meta changes once the page is loaded), so i decided to put it in iframe so i can change meta tags

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question why your code is not working: an `iframe` lets you embed another document; you have to specify its location. You cannot enter HTML code inside the `iframe` tags.

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) says you can insert text between the text for browsers that do not support `iframes`, just like with `noscript` tags.

Take a look at the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe) and just use the `src` attribute and another document.

Comment: So what can i do about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895872/add-metatags-using-javascript